# OLS estimators for a linear log function

Tags: time-series, estimation

So I am doing some linear log functions of the form
$Y_t=\beta_0 + \beta_1*log(t) + X_t$ where $X_t$ is white noise

I have been using R to do the least squares estimations and that easy enough to code in R but I have been looking for the equations/derivatioins of OLS estimators for $\hat\beta_0$ and  $\hat\beta_1$ but I cannot seem to find them on the internet.

I was hoping to find some resources on this and figured statsexchange could point me in the right direction...any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The point estimators are the same as in the general OLS case. You will find those in any introductory text on linear regression,

Comment: Ty appreciate it